# Windows application: fetch only selected columns in gridview from an enum list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview, windows

I am using a simple C# windows application. I am binding the grid view with an enum list.
The problem that I am facing is that I want to fetch only certain columns from the list and not all the columns. Please Help. Below is the code:

```
My list is:

public interface ITransactionLog
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    int DeviceTranLogId { get; set; }
    int ErrorMsgCode { get; set; }
}

var transactionLogList = new List<ITransactionLog>();
var transactionLog = TransactionLogManager.GetAllTransactionLog();
transactionLogList.AddRange(transactionLog);
dataGridView1.DataSource = transactionLogList;
```

I have disabled the auto generated column using:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumn = false;
```

What should i do further?

Comment: I don't see where the enum comes in here.

Comment: can't you see the interface ITransactionLog?
The list transactionLogList is of type enum!

Comment: Actually, `transactionLogList` is of type `ITransactionLog`, which is an interface, not an enum.